# Issue Install Yarn globally on Mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, yarnpkg

I am trying to install yarn globally using npm or brew

```
sudo install --globally yarn
```

or `brew install yarn`

but I still can't use it and I face this problem

[image]

Any clues what's the problem maybe solution?

Comment: What's the result of `ls ~/.config/yarn` ?

Comment: @DevBF the result is  ` /Users/mohameddesouky/.config/yarn: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.config`

Then re-run the install yarn

Comment: This worked. It took me almost half of the day to resolve. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

I'm also trying to install this many times but finally, I'm trying this it works for me. I think it will work for you.