# Facing "yarn not found" error while using terminal every time in mac

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarn-v2

I want to use '`yarn`' package manager to manage packages in my react-native project. I have successfully installed `yarn` package manager in my Mac by this command "`npm install --global yarn`" and set the env path by this command `export PATH=/Users/admin/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`.

All good I am able to use `yarn` after that.

The problem is when I again try to open terminal later than again it shows the "`bash: yarn: command not found`" and I need to set env path.

So how I set path permanently in my Mac, so that later I don't need to set env path again and again.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Not sure if [this answer about using Sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67708458/6060964) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `export PATH=/Users/admin/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` to your .bashrc file, in your home directory:

```bash
cat 'export PATH="/Users/admin/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The content of the `.bashrc` file is run each time bash is started. (except maybe for login shells. In the case of a login shell, I believe `.profile` is run instead)

Comment: Hi Mathieu, Still showing "bash: yarn: command not found" when I am opening terminal again and using the yarn command

Comment: I have tried both command.  export PATH="/Users/admin/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc and export PATH="/Users/admin/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile